# Trying to make a Discord bot respond after a command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I want to create this so, whenever you use the `.choose` and a class after, so either Thief, Mercenary, Hacker or Engineer to change the class of the user but whenever I do try it never works. It always ends up resending the `.choose` command as shown below. How can I edit it so that instead of resending the `.choose` command it actually changes the users class and replies with
" You have chosen the *selected rank* class. "

```
@client.command(aliases = ['Classes'])
async def classes(ctx):
  SelectEmbed = discord.Embed(
    Title = "Class list!",
    colour = discord.Colour.dark_grey()
)
  SelectEmbed.add_field(name = "Available Classes", value = "Mercenary, Hacker, Engineer and Thief.", inline = True)
  await ctx.send(embed=SelectEmbed)

@client.command(aliases = ['Choose','ChoOse'])
async def choose(ctx):
  SelectClass = discord.Embed(
    TItle = "Choose your class!",
    colour = discord.Colour.dark_grey()
  )
  SelectClass.add_field(name = "Select your class below.",value = "Choose a class: use the '.classes' command to view the class list.", inline = True)
  await ctx.send(embed = SelectClass)
```

Comment: You have to set `class` as a required argument then.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is helpful for you

```
@client.command(aliases = ['Classes'])
async def classes(ctx):
  SelectEmbed = discord.Embed(
    Title = "Class list!",
    colour = discord.Colour.dark_grey()
  )
  SelectEmbed.add_field(name = "Available Classes", value = "Mercenary, Hacker, Engineer and Thief.", inline = True)
  await ctx.send(embed=SelectEmbed)

@client.command(aliases = ['Choose','ChoOse'])
async def choose(ctx, name):
  SelectClass = discord.Embed(
    TItle = "Choose your class!",
    colour = discord.Colour.dark_grey()
  )
  SelectClass.add_field(name = "Select your class below.",value = "Choose a class: use the '.classes' command to view the class list.", inline = True)
  await ctx.send(embed = SelectClass)
  await ctx.send(f"You have selected {str(name)}!")
```